# Apples are "in the tree" or "on the tree"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

Apples are "in the tree" or "on the tree"?

Comment: You may find [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-correct-to-say-the-bird-is-in-the-tree-or-on-the-tree) question of interest.

Comment: Apples are on the tree, when you say on the tree it means they exist there, when you say in the trees it means something like the apples are hidden among trees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I hid some apples among the leaves of my lemon tree, they'd be **in** the tree.  But I think you mean that it's an apple tree, and the apples are actually growing on the tree.  In which case, they're **on** the tree.

Answer (score 3):

Apples are on the tree is correct.