# Should it be "... hung it in a tree." or "... hung it on a tree."?

Tags: prepositions

Should it be "... hung it in a tree." or "... hung it on a tree."?

The context is: A person hangs a collop in (on?) a tree.

Comment: Hello, Gopal. Which of these appear/s on the internet?

Comment: There is no rule of syntax or semantics that would prefer one over the other.  It depends on which most appropriately describes the action.

Comment: I've no idea what a *collop* is, but that may not be relevant. You do not appear to have read the tag info as advised, though.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83826/apples-are-in-the-tree-or-on-the-tree) or [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-correct-to-say-the-bird-is-in-the-tree-or-on-the-tree)

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/collop?s=t) defines *collop* as "a small slice of meat, especially a small rasher of bacon". I can't imagine anyone hanging such a thing off a tree, especially not as a regular occurrence (which is what is implied by your description of the context). Did you mean some other word, perhaps?

Comment: @Marthaª - [bad joke warning]: you hang bacon from a tree to fool people. Only once they reach the tree and you start firing at them will they realise that it's not a bacon tree, it's a ham-bush!

Comment: @AndyT: THWACK!

Comment: @AndyT - Ten lashes with a wet noodle!!

Comment: (It's not all that uncommon (in some parts of the world) to hang meat from a tree to "cure" it.  One would normally first pepper it well, to keep the bugs and other critters away.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've never heard "hung in a tree" used, but "hung on a tree" is pretty common, especially depending on what context you use.

For example, since it's the holidays, if you're hanging ornaments, you would say "I hung the ornaments on the tree," rather than "I hung the ornaments in the tree."

Examples of common use for "in" with tree: "The cat got stuck in the tree" or "The string of lights were tangled in the tree."

> **IN** is used to convey that something is *contained* or *inside [of something else]*. E.g., "The mail in the mailbox."
>
> Alternatively, **ON** is used to denote *a position* for surfaces or a
>   position *just above or outside an area*. E.g., "The book is placed on
>   the table." [(Src)](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-in-and-on/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Books' Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hung+it+in+a+tree%2Chung+it+on+a+tree&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chung%20it%20in%20a%20tree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chung%20it%20on%20a%20tree%3B%2Cc0), "hung it on a tree" is used much more often than "hung it in a tree". I also have never heard of the saying "hung it in a tree" when hanging an item on a tree. According to [Udemy Blog](https://blog.udemy.com/in-vs-on/):

> ## On
>
> ---
>
> Typically, you use on whenever you want to denote the position for surfaces or a position just above or outside an area. For instance, whenever setting something on the surface of something: I set a pencil on my desk, or the cup is on the table.
>
> ---
>
> ## In
>
> ---
>
> When using in, you’re typically talking about something contained in an object, or something that is inside. Usually it references something that is in a position with space limitations.
>
> ---

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to hear "hung it in the tree" if we were talking about hammocks, or bird-feeders.

Comment: In the Southwest U.S. (Southern Utah) hearing "in a tree" is common and usually used when referring to live outdoor trees. If it's dead you hang it on the tree, or if it's  alive it's almost always hung in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

*hang something*

to convey location *hang something on* - suggesting up

*in* is suggesting being surrounded by, so

*I was hanging it in the tree*, could be only *I was in the tree hanging it*

For example, *It was me hanging the presents in the picture* is saying what is captured in the photo: me hanging the presents.

Answer (score -2):

I believe both are incorrect.

One would hang something "from a tree".

Comment: It all depends on the context. Any of the three could be correct, in varying situations.

Comment: Grammatically, there is nothing at all wrong with any of the prepositions offered so far (in, on, from) - they just all mean slightly different things. In practice, though, do you mean to say that you go about hanging your ornaments *from* your Christmas tree? Because in my experience, one hangs ornaments *on* a tree.