# Singular and Plural

Tags: grammatical-number

make the following sentence to plural

A bird is on the tree (singular)

Please let me know is it correct to say "Birds are on the trees or Birds are on the tree.

Comment: Both are perfectly valid English. Plurality simply depends on whether you're talking about one bird or many, which are in one tree or many (except obviously if it's only one bird it can only be on one tree). Note that most people would usually refer to birds being ***in*** trees, not ***on*** them.

Comment: And as a stand-alone sentence, it would sound less unnatural to start 'Some birds ...'. // 'A bird is on the trees' might have worked with Argentavis magnificens and medium-sized trees.

Comment: Related: [Is it correct to say “the bird is in the tree” or “on the tree”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-correct-to-say-the-bird-is-in-the-tree-or-on-the-tree)

Answer (score 1):

**"A bird is in the tree"** and **"Birds are in the tree(s)"** are both correct. The lovely comments by FumbleFingers and Edwin Ashworth (above) provide a complete answer. Mr. Ashworth is pointing out that a gigantic extinct bird with a wingspan of 23 feet might be said to be perched "on" a medium-sized tree; otherwise, birds are *usually* described as being "in" trees rather than "on" them. However, it is quite right to say that **"A bird is perched *on a limb*"** or ***"on a branch"*** of a tree. Such is also the case with man-made perches, such as roofs and power lines.